# Ajax post does not reach C# MVC3 controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, post

My problem: When I post data to mvc 3 controller, my controller is not called.

My code:

```
public class Input
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int VId { get; set; }
    public int XId { get; set; }
    public int YId { get; set; }        
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult TestPost(Input input)
 {
    return Json(new { Success = true, Message = "anymessage" });
 }

function TestPost() {
   console.log("TestPost");    
   var obj = { "Id": 1, "VId": 1, "XId": 1, "YId": 2 };
   var objStr = JSON.stringify({ input: obj });    
   console.log("objstr " + objStr);
$.ajax({
    url: '/MyController/TestPost"',        
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: objStr,
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("error");
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
        console.log("b4 send");
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log("success" + JSON.stringify(data));            
    }
});
```

}

When I call the post, I get the following in my console

TestPost

objstr {"input":{"Id":1,"VId":1,"XId":1,"YId":2}}

b4 send

successnull

And, the breakpoint in my controller is not hit. success data is null.

But if I use some REST client like Simple REST or Postman with the same data, my controller is hit, my breakpoint is hit.
So there must be a problem with my call.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
 data:JSON.stringify(obj);
```

What error is there in console? Check it using

```
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
    },
```

Comment: It does not enter the error function, but the success function as seen on the log dump

Comment: So it must be hitting controller. whats the issue then?